# MySQL insert mutiple rows based on SELECT query result

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT cp.plan_name, cp.plan_time FROM courses c
  INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
  INNER JOIN courseplans cp       ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
WHERE cpl.course_id = '$course_id';
```

This will output data like for example:

```
+----------------------------+-----------+
| plan_name                  | plan_time |
+----------------------------+-----------+
| Plan number one name       |         6 |
| Plan number two name       |         6 |
| Plan number three name     |        10 |
+----------------------------+-----------+
```

I want these rows to be inserted in a new table on a form submission.

How do I continue to code my `update.php` to make it insert the values in the table `newtable`?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $course_id = $_POST['course_id'];


 $course_result = mysql_query 
    ("SELECT cp.plan_name, cp.plan_time FROM courses c
      INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
      INNER JOIN courseplans cp       ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
    WHERE cpl.course_id = '$course_id'");

 /* I want the result of the above rows to be inserted in the table
    newtable which has the columns plan_name, plan_time */
```

I hate to admit that I'm completely useless in PHP and MySQL but I'm trying to learn. I guess I have to create some kind of array to store the result and then loop through the inserts but I don't know how.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One thing you have to know is that the number of columns returned by your query must match the number of columns you want to insert into

```
"INSERT INTO NewTable(plan_name, plan_time)
    SELECT cp.plan_name, cp.plan_time 
    FROM courses c
         INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
         INNER JOIN courseplans cp       ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
    WHERE cpl.course_id = '$course_id'"
```

> Warning: watch out for sql injection through `$course_id`.

Note that I specified 2 columns in my INSERT statement because the SELECT query return 2 columns

If the number of columns in your table matches the number of columns returned by the query exactly, then you do not need to specify the columns.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could write SQL querys like that. But now when I see it it so obvious. Thank's again!

Comment: I know I already marked your comment as answer but I have one more question... Is it possible to add more values to the INSERT query besides the ones created by the SELECT? Let's say I have another $_POST value that I want to be inserted in another column together with the rows generated by the SELECT query. Is this possible?

Comment: nvm I fond the solution myself! :)

Comment: what was your answer to that question? How to add more values to the INSERT query besuides the ones created by the SELECT?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the php code but if you change your mysql query to an [insert/select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) it should work:

```
INSERT INTO newtable(plan_name, plan_time)
      SELECT cp.plan_name, cp.plan_time 
      FROM courses c
      INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   
            ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
      INNER JOIN courseplans cp       
            ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
      WHERE cpl.course_id = '$course_id'
```